# What is a Bedspread Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Bedspread Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Bedspread Words™ | Not Bedspread Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| XEROX | PHOTOCOPY |
| FLUFFY | ARAGOG |
| JUJITSU | KARATE |
| BUBBLES | BUTTERCUP |
| ECLECTIC | ASSORTED |
| PINEAPPLE | RASPBERRY |
| CHIHUAHUA | DOGSLEDDED |
| CLOCKWORK | SMOOTHNESS |
| COMMUNISM | COLLECTIVISM |
| ZIGZAGGING* | UNDULATING |

*** This is a Double Bedspread Word™**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Bedspread Words™,Not Bedspread Words™
XEROX,PHOTOCOPY
FLUFFY,ARAGOG
JUJITSU,KARATE
BUBBLES,BUTTERCUP
ECLECTIC,ASSORTED
PINEAPPLE,RASPBERRY
CHIHUAHUA,DOGSLEDDED
CLOCKWORK,SMOOTHNESS
COMMUNISM,COLLECTIVISM
ZIGZAGGING*,UNDULATING
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Bedspread Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Bedspread Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

**Hint:**

> Title: Reference the Greek lizard.

Comment: I had been waiting for a lull in the flow of puzzles of this type to post one of my own, but that lull has never come - so here we go regardless...!

Comment: Is ECLECTIC a typo?

Comment: @Conifers Nope! :)

Comment: Oops I just thought you may want to type "ELECTRIC"... I have to appoint an eye doctor for someday :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following words are Bedspread Words™ because:

> Using the standard number of tiles in a Scrabble set, a blank tile will be needed to write out the word.  If you lookup "Bedspread" in a thesaurus, you will find the word "**Blank**et", which makes sense in this case.

Table:

> [image: number of scrabble pieces in standard set]

Proof:

> **X**ERO**X** (1 X in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  **F**LU**FF**Y (2 Fs in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  **J**U**J**ITSU (1 J in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  **B**U**BB**LES (2 Bs in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  E**C**LE**C**TI**C** (2 Cs in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  **P**INEA**PP**LE (2 Ps in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  C**H**I**H**UA**H**UA (2 Hs in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  CLOC**K**WOR**K** (1 K in Scrabble, 1 blank tile);
>  CO**MM**UNIS**M** (2 Ms in Scrabble, 1 blank tile).

---

Words which are not Bedspread Words™

> can be made with the standard Scrabble letter count.

ZIGZAGGING is a Double Bedspread Word™ because:

> ZI**G**ZA**GG**IN**G** (3 Gs and 1 Z in Scrabble, 1 blank tile for G, 1 blank tile for Z)...
>
>  Therefore, two blank (bedspread) tiles are needed.

Comment: You're pretty much there, although you've missed BUBBLES in your 'Proof' section. You also need the title - I'll add a hint...

Comment: @Stiv The only thing I was able to come up with was the greek lizard type of camo, which could make sense for the blank tiles.  But I wasn't able to make a connection to "Bedspread".

Comment: It's a cryptic crossword clue. Look up words that might mean 'lizard' in Greek. In fact, doing exactly that might give you an idea of what you need to do with 'bedspread'!

Comment: I've made a small edit to your answer to make the text content of the 'Proof' section image more accessible to screen readers, etc. (hope you don't mind). For the final explanation I recommend looking up the word 'bedspread' in a reference book which is not a dictionary...!

Comment: I think the key word for explaining the title is rot13(_oynax_rg), though I'm not sure where the Greek lizards come in.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the Greek lizard is just explaining what sort of reference book to look in: rot13(gur_fnhehf_).

Comment: @Stiv Wow, I am slow.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Huzzah! All solved and the checkmark is yours :) Thanks for completing it!

Comment: See also: [List of Over-bedspread words](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48647/#)

Answer (score 7):

I didn't check everything rigorously yet, but I think a Bedspread Word

> can be spelled using a standard Scrabble set, but only with the help of the blank wildcard tile(s).

(Those kind of look like bed sheets, too.)

Comment: Well, check it rigorously, add some explanatory detail for each word (including the Double Bedspread word) and nail down that title... and then the green checkmark can be yours! :)